# Difference of a ring and its module over itself

Tags: ring-theory, modules

What is the difference of a ring $R$ and the module $R_R$? It looks like they are just the same thing. Is it correct that the difference is $R$ is a ring with multiplication defined but $R_R$ is an Abelian group with addition defined only?

Comment: "with addition defined only"...and a scalar product by the elements of the ring $\;R\;$ ,  which is the same (AFAIK, although they may be some special cases in which it is not) as the product within the ring.

Comment: One is a ring, the other is an $R$-module. The ring has an operation called "multiplication" and (if you use my definition of a ring) a unity $1_R$; the module has an operation called "right $R$-action" which happens to be the same as the ring's multiplication but serves a different role. Endomorphisms of the ring $R$ are not the same as endomorphisms of the $R$-module $R$, so it pays to distinguish between the two. Think of them in terms of OOP: two objects might store the same data but have different methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost. It's the same thing, except that you forget the "internal" multiplication. It's more than an abelian group, because you can multiply an element of R (viewed as a module element)  on the left by another element of R (viewed as a ring element),  but it doesn't make sense anymore to multiply two elements of R together, viewing them both as module elements.